# I have a String[], can i use Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

What i got for code is

```
    String[] food = new String[]{"Salads", "Sandwiches", "Drinks"};
    // My own layout = rowlayout.xml with id = label
    setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, food ) );
```

Now i want to add an Intent to every item of the String[], but the problem is that there is no id for the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a ListActivity.  You can override the `onListItemClick` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can then use the position to decide what intent to create.